# adding values to the arraylist from userinput dynamically

Tags: java, android

How can we add the data to java objects dynamically by taking the input from user?
without using database is that possible? if possible how ? show with small example
thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
EditText myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){
myArrayList.add(myText.getText().toString());
```